Есть ли ошибка в решении задачи на тему союза ЛИ...ИЛИ?
Заданный вопрос: Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?
Пример: Действительно ли старые обиды забываются(,) или мы только прячем их в душе с прошествием времени?
Ответ 1. Нет, не нужна: запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения выражены двумя вопросительными предложениями (источник информации).
Ответ 2. Присоединяюсь к ответу Noir. Если части сложносочиненного предложения что-то объединяет (общий второстепенный член, вводной слово, общее придаточное, общая интонация), то запятая перед союзами И, ИЛИ не ставится. В данном случае объединяющий элемент - это вопросительная интонация. См. справочник по орфографии и пунктуации под ред.Лопатина. Параграф 112
И вот мне кажется, что ответ неверен, если ориентироваться на Розенталя (пункт 5, примечания):

если ли…или соединяют независимые вопросительные предложения, перед или ставится запятая: Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерёте прохожих? (Г.) [См. § 30, п. 1, прим. 1.]
Во сне ль всё это снится мне, или гляжу я в самом деле, на что при этой же луне с тобой живые мы глядели? (Тютч.);

Также у  Лермонтова: Судьба ли нас свела опять на Кавказе, или она нарочно сюда приехала, зная, что меня встретит?
Также у Пушкина: В ней сердце долго ли страдало, иль скоро слёз прошла пора? (П.)
Вопрос: Так правильно ли решена задача для заданного вопроса (8 голосов за!), или это все-таки ошибочное решение? И если ошибка, то в чем причина непонимания темы?

Мне кажется тут действительно(модальное) относится только к первой части высказывания, поэтому его в любом случае надо запятой отделить. Если бы было "неужели", то возможно, наверное, без запятой.

Тут другая подстава. Участники стали общий  элемент искать  для ССП (вопросительную интонацию), а это не следует делать.

В справочнике Розенталя  четко сказано:"...запятая перед или не ставится, если ли…или соединяют однородные члены предложения, и ставится, если они соединяют части предложения.
Запятая в вашем примере нужна!

Спасибо, Серж, за ответ. Я  тоже думаю, что запятая нужна. Но  вы еще скажите, почему все участники  (8 голосов, практически весь форум) допустили ошибку? Люди-то не последние, а Ларf вроде бы педагог. Они-то правила хорошо знают.  И никто за 10 лет не обратил на это внимание. Да и вы в 2014 году там были.

А был ли я? Шарон, возможно, они ссылаются на общую вопросительную интонацию в ССП. А про этот пункт не знали. Но вот почему Ларф не знала, странно.

Шарон, а кто просматривает 10 летние вопросы?

Это я, а что вас удивляет?) ) Мне надо (для своей работы) хорошо разобраться с этой темой (союз ЛИ...ИЛИ), а я недовольна своими знаниями (нет четкого понимания).  Вот откуда Розенталь взял это правило, уж оно очень похоже на формальное. И он его интересно формулирует. Сначала рассматривает конкретные случаи, а потом как бы делает вывод.  Выучить  формулировку правила несложно,  но нужно найти его причину. Кстати,  в 2017 году М.Г. редактирует вопрос, но не делает никаких выводов, то есть считает ответ правильным. А он тоже хорошо знал правила, внимательный был участник.

Шарон, но правила же не он придумывал.

Не он, и не другие академики в 1956 году) Каждое правило проверено на практике в классической литературе и имеет грамматическое обоснование. Вот грамматика меня и интересует.

Вы правы. Правила создавались годами. А он и другие академики унифицировали правила, закрепили.

Союз ЛИ...ИЛИ – это вопросительная частица ЛИ + союз ИЛИ.  В разных конструкциях получаются разные решения: одиночный союз  / повторяющийся союз.

При однородных членах предложения следует рассматривать в качестве одиночного союза.

Повторяющиеся союзы ЛИ... ЛИ и ЛИ... ИЛИ предполагают, что   
говорящий сам не знает, какой из возможных компонентов 
присутствует. Повторяющийся союз ЛИ... ИЛИ следует отличать 
от сочетания вопросительной частицы ЛИ с одиночным 
разделительным союзом ИЛИ:

Русская корпусная грамматика, пункт 5.1.5. Союзы ли... ли и ли... или

Правильно: Действительно ли старые обиды забываются, или мы только прячем их в душе с прошествием времени?

В вопросительном сложносочиненном предложении ССП составной союз ЛИ...ИЛИ является повторяющимся, а не одиночным (ЛИ относится к первому простому предложению, а ИЛИ ко второму). Поэтому вопросительная интонация не является общим элементом и запятая   ставится.

Для сравнения: Действительно ли старые обиды забываются или остаются в душе навсегда?

В вопросительном простом предложении используется вопросительная частица ЛИ (ЛИ относится ко всему предложению, а одиночный союз ИЛИ соединяет однородные сказуемые). Поэтому при наличии общей вопросительной интонации запятая не ставится.

Из таких рассуждений делается вывод у Розенталя: Следовательно, запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится, если ЛИ...ИЛИ соединяет однородные члены предложения, и ставится, если ЛИ...ИЛИ соединяет части сложного предложения.

